# Safety Inspection after repair

Tags: inspection

My car was recently repaired (turbo air intake motor, motor mounts, brakes) at which time I also asked them to do the annual NC safety inspection.

When I picked up the car and asked about the inspection, the shop rep said he couldn't do it because the car had just been repaired and needed to "run in" for a week or so before he could hook it up to the machine.

I've never heard of this "run-in" period before. Is this true? Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the codes have been cleared, and likely were after the repairs, the car has to pass a couple of emission inspection test that the ECM (the cars computer) runs once certain conditions are met. This usually takes a few drive cycles to get all the tests to run.

The car will not pass the inspection until these tests have run. This keeps someone for clearing the codes just before putting in on the inspection machine to make the car pass inspection even when there are problems with the car.